# Sort an array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need some help with sorting this Array of Objects:

```
Array
    (
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [registrationType] => payment
        [registry] => 1
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [registrationType] => payment
        [registry] => 0
    )

    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [registrationType] => payment
        [registry] => 0
    )

    [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [registrationType] => bankWithdrawal
        [registry] => 0
    )

    [4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [registrationType] => payment
        [registry] => 0
    )

    [5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [registrationType] => depoitBank
        [registry] => 1
    )

    [6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [registrationType] => cashing
        [registry] => 0
    )

    [7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [registrationType] => cashing
        [registry] => 1
    )

    [8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [registrationType] => cashing
        [registry] => 0
    )
)
```

I need to sort it like this:

1. First I want it to be sorted by an order like

(cashing, depositBank, bankWithdrawal, payment)

2. Then the cashing and payment should be sorted by the registery like

(cashing[with registery 0], cashing[with registery 1] depositBank, bankWithdrawal, payment[with registery 0], payment[with registery 1])

The end result should be this: `Array([1],[2],[4],[0],[5],[3],[6],[8],[7])`

Comment: You can use [`usort()`](https://secure.php.net/usort) to sort an array by your own logic. Try that and let us know if you have any specific issues with it.

Comment: As per your first point, I haven't found anything related to sorting. See your sorting sequence.

Comment: Yeah but I don't really get how usort() works. More exactly how should I make it to have this order when sorting: (cashing, depositBank, bankWithdrawal, payment)

Comment: @RaresPop have you solved this ? or need help ?

Comment: To sort by `registrationType`, just loop over the array and add each item to a respective array containing only that `registrationType`, and then use `array_merge`. The items will then be sorted.